# How to write Sparql endpoint to DBpedia in java

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

Below is the sparql query to get places in united state, When I run this code on virtuoaso SPARQL I get the required output. But when I write this code in java its not giving the output.

```sql
  select (str(?label) as ?strLabel) where {  
    ?place a dbpedia-owl:PopulatedPlace ;
     dbpedia-owl:country dbpedia:United_States ;
     rdfs:label ?label
 filter langMatches( lang(?label), 'en' )`
 }
 limit 100
```

To my knowledge I wrote it but its not giving any result.

```java
   public class TestDbpedia {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sparqlQueryString = " select (str(?label) as ?strLabel) "+
                            "where {"+
                            "?place a dbpedia-owl:PopulatedPlace ;"+
                            "dbpedia-owl:country dbpedia:United_States ;"+
                            "rdfs:label ?label"+                                
                            "filter langMatches( lang(?label), 'en' )"+
                            "limit 10"+
                            "}";

                    Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQueryString);

                    QueryExecution qexec =   QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);


                    try {
                        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
                        for ( ; results.hasNext() ; )
                    {
                        QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution() ;                           
                        System.out.println(soln.get("?strLabel"));                               
                    }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }    

                    finally { qexec.close(); }

                    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You need to declare the prefixes

One, you need to include the necessary prefixes in your SPARQL query.  That is, you'll need to write

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
```

and the rest at the beginning of your query.  The predefined prefixes only get applied to queries you make with the browser-based web interface, as far as I know.

### You need to use some spaces or newlines

When you're constructing queries from strings, you need to be very careful with newlines and spaces and the like.  For instance, the Java lines

```java
"rdfs:label ?label"+                                
"filter langMatches( lang(?label), 'en' )"+
```

end up giving you a query string containing

```
rdfs:label ?labelfilter langMatches( lang(?label), 'en' )
```

You end up with an invalid query. Add some spaces or newlines to your strings.

### You need to write a proper query

Your query doesn't *end* correctly.  You have

```java
"filter langMatches( lang(?label), 'en' )"+
"limit 10"+
"}";
```

which will give you (once you add some newlines and spaces):

```
  filter …
  limit 10
}
```

That's not the right syntax.  You need to have

```
  filter …
}
limit 10
```

### Print and check your queries if you don't get useful error messages

I'm surprised that DBpedia didn't give you a more useful error message (or maybe it did;  you didn't show us the stacktrace, after all).  You can test your queries at [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html), too.  Also, if you used one of Jena's ParameterizedSparqlStrings, you could have parsed the query beforehand, which should have caught the syntax error.

Comment: If it worked for you, do consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437) the answer. If it doesn't completely work, is there something that could be improved?

Comment: It was the answer I needed, I have followed all ur instructions which were a detailed explanation. I really understood each and every point you mentioned. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: After adding the Prefix I still get the error which I mentioned in the other question but I realized I dint mention the prefix. Can you please say why I am getting the error. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You didn't show any particular error.  You need to show the error message that you got.  However, since you keep saying "the prefix" rather than "the prefixes", I'm guessing that you only added one, rather than all three.  You need to add  prefix declarations for all the prefixes that you use: rdfs:, dbpedia:, and dbpedia-owl:.